# Verifying an existing Micro chip RF component range with my calculations

Tags: rf, antenna, microchip, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to understand how the microchip RN4871 chip range is calculated. I know the chip Antenna used in this module.

According to its datasheet, RN4871 has a range of 10m. So my calculations should yield this result. Else 
I did something wrong.

I put all the parameters in a range calculator I found online (link below) and the result doesn't match up.

https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/Antenna-Range-Calculator.html

Transmit Antenna gain = 0.45 dB mean effective gain(Antenna Datasheet fig 5), also tried 0.1 dB (RN4871 datasheet fig8-2)
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/yageo/ANT3216LL00R2400A/311-4590-1-ND/9360410

Transmit power = 0 dBm (RN4071 data sheet) https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/RN4871-V-RM118/RN4871-V-RM118-ND/6130476

Operating frequency = 2.45GHz

cable loss = -27.3 dB (Antenna datasheet at 2.45 Hz, figure 4)

Receiver sensitivity = -70

I get a range of 815 m which is not the case (it's 10 m).

But if I change the cable loss to an acceptable estimate of 10 dB, then I get the correct range of 10.26 m. Is the Antenna return loss graph (Fig 4) incorrect? Or did I understand it wrong

which is more likely. Can you please explain?

Also, the gain is highest (5.5 dB) in certain directions. So is the range of more than 10 m in those directions? and range 10 m is mean effective range?

Thank you

Comment: You reduced the cable loss from -27.3 dB to - 10 dB (and so increased the ERP) and the calculated range decreased?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Exactly...Cable loss is the amount of wave reflected. Do you think the calculator is not expecting negative sign?

Antenna datasheet shows -27dB but the negative sign is to denote the direction of wave propagation ?

Comment: No.  The amount of energy reflected back from the antenna into the cable (when transmitting) is the return loss, or the S11 parameter.  It's a measure of how well the cable and the antenna are matched.  Cable loss is a combination of resistive and dielectric losses.  You have cable losses even when the cable and the antenna are perfectly matched.

Comment: As for how the calculator handles something like a cable loss...  If you're trying the specify the loss in something, IMO, you would say something like "the loss is 10 dB".  Saying "the loss is - 10 dB" is having two negatives in that statement (loss and the negative sign), and really means that the cable (or whatever it is) has a gain of 10 dB.  So I can't say for sure what the calculator is looking for.

Comment: I understand that. Once you design the antenna, you plot the S11 parameter on a graph. With this you know the best operating frequency of the designed Antenna, also called resonant frequency. From the datasheet of the antenna used by RN4871, it says return loss is as follows:
1. 2.37GHz, -10dB
2. 2.45GHz, -27.3dB
3. 2.53GHz, -10dB 
hence I took -27.3 dB as my cable loss.

Comment: I understand. I'm confused too. One last question regarding the Antenna's datasheet. if the negative sign is just indicating direction, then how is the magnitude of return loss higher for other frequencies other than tuned frequency?

Comment: The loss, (or gain) of a cable is also called the S21 parameter.  If the cable's S21 parameter is -10 dB, you know unequivocally that's a loss, because of the negative sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107847/discussion-between-stevesh-and-varun).